# .NET 6. Parallel processing, refill queue when less than MaxDegreesOfParallelism threads are running

Tags: .net, multithreading, async-await, parallel-processing, .net-6.0

I'd like to process some data in parallel using a `BackgroundService`.

There may be more than `MaxDegreesOfParallelism` items to process in the database, but as the processing can take several minutes per row, I'd like to only load as many items into the local processing queue as can actually be processed, so I avoid having potentially outdated data.

For example, if there are 20 items to be processed in the database and `MaxDegreesOfParallelism` (the number of concurrent processing jobs allowed) is 10, I only want to load 10 items. After a few minutes, the first 3 items may be done processing. At this point, I want to load the next 3 items from the database. Of course I could load all 20 items when the program starts, but when "processing slots" become available after a few minutes, those 20 items may no longer reflect the current state of the database.

I guess I could use a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` for this - but how would I know when "processing slots" become available? It wouldn't have to be immediate, it would be OK if the "data loading" service/thread could check every minute or so how many "processing slots" are available and load the corresponding number of items to be added to the processing queue.

Or maybe I should just use `Task.WhenAny`, so that I could load additional items as soon as the first item has been processed? But then I'd still need to know how many "slots" are available. (But I could use the database to track that, hmmm...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using TPL dataflow. You can use ActionBlock with BoundedCapacity to limit the number of items that get queued.

ActionBlock will then await on SendAsync call. SendAsync will be blocked when the buffer fills up (preventing additional records from being fetched, until a record completes processing, allowing SendAsync to push the next record.)

```
Action<int> fn = record => {
Thread.Sleep(1000); // record processing task goes here.
Console.WriteLine(record);
};

var opts = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 5, MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 };
// Sets the block's buffer size to one message

var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<int>(fn, opts);

while (true /* add your exit condition here */) {
    var record = GetFromDB(index++);
    await actionBlock.SendAsync(record);  
    // After first 5 records, the bounded capacity will prevent additional records from being fetched until one of the existing records gets processed.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the first time I'm hearing about TPL dataflow, that definitely looks very interesting. I don't think I'd need `BoundedCapacity` because I only care about `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`. I could actually just handle the refilling on a separate thread and manage the number of "slots" through status flags in the database. But then I wonder if there would be an advantage with using `ActionBlock<T>` over a simple `ConcurrentQueue<T>`?

Comment: Are you planning on using Parallel.ForEach with ConcurrentQueue to enforce MaxDegreeOfParallelism? I'm not sure how you plan on limiting the number of items that get queued in ConcurrentQueue in that case. You'd need to provide more detail on your current plan. ActionBlock manages the "processing slots" automatically thru MaxDegreeOfParallelism and BoundedCapacity ensures that you don't queue up too many items, so it's a great fit for your scenario.

Comment: When the processing jobs start, they mark the items as being processed in the database anyway. So I can get the number of running tasks from the database instead. I only see a (negligible) risk for a race condition: An item could be dequeued, but not yet marked as "processing" in the database. Then the queuing service could add it to the internal processing queue again. But that would lead to an error, so it should be fine.

Comment: To put it differently, your code is very close to what I need, but as far as I understand, it loads a record and if the capacity limit has been reached, it waits before it starts processing the record. That is not what I want - because by then the record may be outdated. I want to delay the loading of new data from the database, until there is capacity to start processing it immediately.

Comment: Note that you don't necessarily need to fetch full record to post to ActionBlock. You can fetch <ID list to be processed> and when an ID gets picked for processing, the Record can be fetched within fn function. This way the record that's being processed is always "fresh". ActionBlock's main purpose here is to prevent "excessive concurrency" thru MaxDegreeOfParallelism. Ensuring you're processing the "latest version" of record can always be guaranteed through DB locks etc. (i.e. there are established methods for doing that... and it has nothing to do with parallel proc.)